# Compare two lists and find if all elements of the first are also in the second

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two Lists of String objects in Java and what I would like to have is a method which will return `true` if all elements of my first list are also elements of the second.

For instance:

```
List<String> validCombination: [3, 5, 12]
List<String> currentCombincation: [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 12, 14]
```

Since `currentCombination` has all the elements of the `validCombination` my method should return `true`.

In the case that `currentCombination` was missing one or more elements of `validCombination`, e.g.

```
List<String> validCombination: [3, 5, 12]
List<String> currentCombincation: [2, 4, 5, 7, 12, 14]
```

it should return `false`.

Any ideas on how to implement it in Java?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Also you could use a `List<Integer>`. I don't see why it would be a `List<String>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`List#containsAll(Collection<?> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) method which returns `true` if the list contains all the elements of the given `Collection`. For example:

```
boolean containsAll = currentCombination.containsAll(validCombination);
```

Since you need a method, it can be written like this:

```
public static boolean contains(List<?> currentCombination, List<?> validCombination) {
    return currentCombination.containsAll(validCombination);
}
```

Comment: Note that that method could be static.

Answer (score 1):

***`boolean containsAll(Collection<?> args)`*** is the method you can use for your solution

as

```
if(currentCombincation.containsAll(validCombination))
    {
        return true;
    }
```